# MonoTouch: how to add UITabBarController

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, monodevelop

A bit confused with wiring controllers, I need some help

I create a new Monotouch project (Master-Detail). Now, when I click on the tableview, I want to load a new view with a tabbar. SO I double-click on the DetailViewController.xib, and drag-drop a new `UITabBarController`. But how do I specify that I want this newly created tabbar to be displayed, instead of the empty view originally there?

Or if I had another tabbar in the same .xib, how do I specify which one to launch when the DetailViewController gets loaded?

Btw, I tried changing the DetailViewController class to inherit from `UITabTarController`, but then I see an empty black screen with no tabs, as opposed to the two tabs already created in XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

In your `AppDelegate FinishedLaunching()` method you would have code like:

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
viewController = new UITabBarController();
navController = new UINavigationController(viewController);

window.RootViewController = navController;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

else you can just skip the `UINavigationController` bit.  You've read all the tutorials at the MonoTouch site?

Comment: I was looking for an XCode solution, but yours sounds reasonable